# How to define type 'a child class of' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, types

In the following example, the `list1` attribute of `P` represents a list of instances of A.

```py
class A:
   value1: str

class B(A):
   value2: str

class P:
   list1: List[A]
```

I want is to keep a list of child classes of `A` (not instances of `A`) in the variable `list1`. Is there a way to do it in python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)

Comment: Are you asking how to type-hint such a list, or how to create it?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the answer. That's what I was looking for exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type.

```py
from typing import List, Type

class P:
   list1: List[Type[A]]
```

Now, `list1` represents a list of classes extended from A.

Comment: Sorry to bother I am new to python but do your variables annotations look like functions annotstions ?? Here they show them differently: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/ . Maybe I need to figure it out better

Answer (score 0):

my try copying from first answer here :[How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name) :

```
class klass():
    pass



class popo(klass):
    pass

class pepe(klass):
    pass



class P():
    

    def get_all_subclasses(self, cls):
        subclass_list = []
    
        def recurse(classe):
            for subclass in classe.__subclasses__():
                subclass_list.append(subclass)
                recurse(subclass)
    
        recurse(cls)
    
        return list(set(subclass_list))

a = P()


print(a.get_all_subclasses(klass),'\n')

print(type(a.get_all_subclasses(klass)),'\n')


class papa(klass):
    pass

class coco(popo):
    pass


print(a.get_all_subclasses(klass),'\n')
```

output:

```
[<class '__main__.popo'>, <class '__main__.pepe'>] 

<class 'list'> 

[<class '__main__.papa'>, <class '__main__.popo'>, <class '__main__.pepe'>, <class '__main__.coco'>]
```

or :

```
class klass:
    pass


class popo(klass):
    pass


class pepe(klass):
    pass


class P:
    def __init__(self, classez):
        self.list1 = []

        self.get_all_subclasses(classez)

        pass

    def get_all_subclasses(self, cls):
        def recurse(classe):
            for subclass in classe.__subclasses__():
                self.list1.append(subclass)
                recurse(subclass)  # necessarioo per avere coco nella lista

        recurse(cls)

        self.list1 = list((self.list1))

        return self.list1


a = P(klass)

print(a.list1, "\n")

print(type(a.list1), "\n")


class papa(klass):
    pass


class coco(popo):
    pass


a = P(klass)


print(a.list1)
```

I get too:

```
[<class '__main__.popo'>, <class '__main__.pepe'>] 

<class 'list'> 

[<class '__main__.popo'>, <class '__main__.coco'>, <class '__main__.pepe'>, <class '__main__.papa'>]
```

using :

```
class klass():
    pass



class popo(klass):
    pass

class pepe(klass):
    pass


print(klass.__subclasses__(),'\n')



class papa(klass):
    pass

class coco(popo):
    pass


print(klass.__subclasses__(),'\n')
```

I get:

```
[<class '__main__.popo'>, <class '__main__.pepe'>] 

[<class '__main__.popo'>, <class '__main__.pepe'>, <class '__main__.papa'>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type.

Comment: Okeydokey wasnt sure you were aking help about annotations

Answer (score -1):

```
...
class P:
    A.__subclasses__()

>>> [<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>]
```

**subclasses** - Returns a list of weak references to classes directly inherited from this one.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877110/python-new-style-classes-and-subclasses-function)

Comment: The question is how to specify the type.

Comment: Is that what you mean?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092104/subclass-in-type-hinting

Comment: @Keith the question is not clear, two of us interpreted it the same way